# Can we install eli5 package in spyder for python 3.6

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have installed eli5 in command prompt where the python scripts located in c folder. I tried to import eli5 package but it shows there is no package. How to resolve it

Comment: How did you install eli5? Did you use pip3, or did you download the wheel or the tar? And what is this 'c' folder?

Comment: I installed using pip3. C folder is where the python scripts are there. Many told that should install the eli5 where python scripts are located.